# Insert distinct entries from column x of Table A and column y of Table B into two columns in Table C

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert distinct combination of `Flowmeter` column of table `A` and `RecordTime` column of table `B` into table `C` ensuring that no such combination to be selected.
Also the query should avoid inserting the select query output to table `C` *if* this combination is found in table `C` by using the `WHERE` clause.

I have written the below script but it seems not to be working. Especially the distinct filter for filtering the distinct entries from the two joined tables:

```
INSERT INTO C (MeterId,PresRecTimestamp,PresUnits,PresVal)
SELECT DISTINCT A.FlowMeter,
                B.RecordTime,
                substring(B.FormattedValue,
                          CHARINDEX(' ',B.FormattedValue)+1,
                          LEN(B.FormattedValue)),
                substring(B.FormattedValue, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',B.FormattedValue)-1)
FROM  B
INNER JOIN  A ON  A.Id = B.Id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM C
                  WHERE C.MeterId = A.FlowMeter
                    AND C.PresRecTimestamp = B.RecordTime)
```

Appreciating your help so much.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with your current query, but you might simply switch to an "Insert Only" `MERGE ... WHEN NOT MATCHED` instead

Comment: DISTINCT gives you distinct rows. So from a mere technical point of view it is possible to get two records for the same FlowMeter and RecordTime, but different FormattedValue substrings, as these, too, are part of the row selected. Whether this really happens depends on your data of course.

Comment: BTW: The substring expressions seem to indicate that you have multiple values in a single string (one value before the blank and one after). That shouldn't be done in a relational database. Use two separate columns instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, So i think that if I modified the Distinct to select only the distinct combination of the FlowMeter and RecordTime out of the other rows should solve my issue, do you have any recommendations how to do So ?